# Why `sorted` and not `sort` in Python?

Tags: python

Being new to the language, I am unable to get my head around why in Python the two built-in functions `sorted` and `reversed` are named in the past participle form, while others like `format` or `filter` are named in the verb form.

Why could not have these functions been named `sort` and `reverse` instead, like in several other languages?

Semantically, I would rather expect *`sorted`* returning a boolean -- as in *sorted?*, indicating whether or not the list passed is sorted, but that could be because of the influence that other languages have had on me.

But is there a reason in naming `sorted` and `reversed` this way that I am unable to see?

---

**Updating** since almost all answers/comments are missing the point. I am aware that both functions return new objects without modifying what is passed to them.

But in the same spirit, could `filter` not be named `filtered`, and `format` not be named `formatted`? Would that not be more consistent naming across the language?

---

**Update 2**: Since this question is supposedly *opinion based*, it probably was just the language designer's opinion to name it such. Probably there was no rationale behind naming Python's built-in functions and keeping them consistent.

If there was a rationale, please help answer if `format` could also have been `formatted` for uniformity and consistency?

Comment: Because sorted is returning a new list, it isn't operating on the given list

Comment: So what your question is about? Changing syntax of language?

Comment: `sorted(lst)` returns a sorted version of `lst`. That works for me.

Comment: You might already know this, but `sort` and `reverse` do exist in Python, as list methods. I speculate that the built-in functions `sorted` and `reversed` were given different names, because they do different things than their method counterparts. In particular, the methods mutate the list in-place and return None, while the functions do not mutate and return a new copy or iterator of the object with the desired modifications.

Comment: I would actually expect something like `if issorted(lst):` in your example; I guess `sorted` could be seen as a short form of that, but it can also become confusing.

Comment: It's only confusing if you don't realize that *every* value in Python has a "truthiness" value. `if sorted(list)` doesn't check if the list is sorted; it checks if the result of sorting the list produces an empty list (false) or a non-empty list (true).

Comment: @Sayse, I do know that. But why not `formatted` and `filtered`. Did not read the full question perhaps?

Comment: I must have missed the part in your question where you explain that fact. Also, your if statement does *not* check to see if the list is sorted.

Comment: Asking why a function was given one name or another is pretty much opinion-based.

Comment: @chepner, a 'why' question may be opinion based. But I am just trying to understand the thinking behind it, not suggest a change to the language.

Comment: `L.sort()` *sorts* a list; `sorted(L)` returns the *sorted* list. While I can see `sorted` being ambiguous, there is an obvious alternative to the Boolean-value function: `is_sorted`, with no such elegant alternative for what `sorted` actually does.

Answer (score 4):

In Python, `sort` is the in-place sort function, and `sorted` is the function that returns the new sorted collection:

```
a = [2,3,1,4]
print(sorted(a))
print(a)
print(a.sort())
print(a)
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
[2, 3, 1, 4]
None
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

The first print is the sorted list. The original list is not changed after it. The third print is the result of `a.sort` - `None` (because it returns nothing). And the original list is sorted after this function call.

The same behavior works for `reverse/reversed` functions.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am aware that `sorted` returns a new list.

But in the same spirit could `filter` not be `filtered`, and `format` not be `formatted`.